# drawings in TikZ not affected by scale

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've created command that displays a small filled circle to represent a point using TikZ. When I change yscale, i get an ellipse instead of a circle. I understand why but I can't figure a way to avoid this.
Any ideas on how I should proceed ?

`\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\mycircle}[2]{\draw[fill = gray] (#1,#2) circle (0.1cm)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=0.5]
        \clip (0,0) rectangle (3,5);
        \draw[domain=0.01:3,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{1/\x});
        \mycircle{1}{1}; % I'd like this to remain a circle
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Depending on the way you scale, different tikz elements and sizes may be affected differently; some may be scaled, others not. So we need to know how you draw the circle and how you scale. Please provide a complete document.

Answer (score 2):

You can either re-scale the circle with the inverse of the scale of the figure, or use a node to draw the circle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.5]
  \draw[thick](0,0) circle (40mm);
  \draw[thick,yscale=2,fill=green](0,0) circle (20mm);
  \node[circle,inner sep=2mm,fill=red] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]